# Does anybody know how can I make a table like this?

Tags: tables

I am writing my final degree but I can´t find on the web something that could help me. I would like to do a table like this. I tried to use `\multirow{}{}`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? BTW, just write standard table and for lines in rows "Course 1" ... "Course 4" use `\cline{2-3}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me extend my comment to answer. For starting point can serve the following MWE (minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|}
    \hline
\thead{Column 1}    &   \thead{Column 2}    &   \thead{Column 3}    \\
    \hline
Course 1            &   Some information    &   Another information \\
    \cline{2-3}
Course 2            &   Some information    &   Another information \\
    \cline{2-3}
Course 3            &   Some information    &   Another information \\
    \cline{2-3}
Course 4            &   Some information    &   Another information \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks  @Zarko :)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility (as outlined by @Zarko) would be to use `\cline`to draw a line under in the desired cells.
For the kind of table you want to write, the code could look like this :

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
...

Course 1 & Same Information & Another same information\\\cline{2-3}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks @v_manz